# Change Image on runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

I am able to now change an image when pressing OnTouch, for example I press image1 make it invisible and show the one i have underneath it...

Now i want to change an image on runtime, basically I have an array if array[i] = 5; then i want to make image5 invisible?

How can I do this?, I tried it with a

```
try{
     Thread.sleep(2000);
     }
catch
  {
  }
```

and it blacks out the screen and then shows the backgroung after 2 seconds but i never see the image get invisible;

i would like to be able to do something like this

```
for(int i=0;i < array.length; i++)
{
 if(array[i] == 1)
     {
          try
          {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
         ImageView image = (ImageView)findById(myImage01);
         image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);      
         Thread.sleep(1000);
         image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  

           }  
         catch(InterruptedException e) 
            {
            }
       }
```

}

You get the idea... right now if i do this it will black out the screen and then return to the main layout and do nothing :(

Thank you in advance

By the way I am new in Android (please consider :(  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread.sleep() is a bad idea because it halts the thread. So if it is the UI-thread, it can not refresh the screen anymore. That's probably what you observe. Use something like

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
  void run() {
      image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: where would I implement this if in myView Class?

Comment: you could create a method `switchImage` that toggles the image visibility or changes the image. Then you'd call `switchImage` inside the `run`method of the Handler. Also you would call Handler.postDelayed there again.

Answer (score 2):

Lets see if i understand this correctly. You are trying to show an image by turning an image, that is placed above it, invisible?

It seems that the easier way would be to change the image of the actual imageview your are turning invisible.

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.<image>)
```

Where you change  to the name of the image placed inside your res/drawable-hdpi/mdpi/ldpi folder.

Comment: That sounds good but what about the screen blacking out when using Thread.sleep ?  :(

Comment: My guess it is blacking out because the UI thread is put to sleep.